# How to make a nested src tag directory optional in Ant´s javac task?

Tags: ant

It is possible to make a `fileset` optional by setting the attribute `erroronmissingdir` to false.

How to do the same with an embedded `src` node in the `javac` task?

I have a source directory which always exists and I have an source directory with generated source files which exists only sometimes. If I try this:

```
<javac>
  <src path="${src-dir}"/>
  <src path="${build-dir}/${src-dir}" erroronmissingdir="false"/>
</javac>
```

I get the error that the attribute `erroronmissingdir` is not supported by the `src` element. The there an alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to encapsulate filset within a src.

```
<src>
    <fileset dir="${build-dir}/${src-dir}" erroronmissingdir="false"/>
</src>
```

Let me know if that works for you.